# Pseudo data table/spreadsheet without Core Data

Tags: objective-c

I'm interested in organizing and saving some data to disk without using Core Data, and in particular I want to have a data table consisting of ordered rows with many fields.

I'm thinking the best or easiest way to do this is to have an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`s, where the dictionaries hold the contents for each column/field and the array makes up the "rows" of my data table.

Does this seem like a simple and good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is fine if your tables are small. For larger tables I would favor NSArray of NSArray. This avoids having to save the column names for each row (smaller saved files) and is closer to the real structure of a table.